# Query to retrive rows with words starting and ending with same character in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL Server query to filter the rows with sentences containing first and last character of the sentence being same like [image: here]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where left(col, 1) = right(col, 1);
```

By default, SQL Server comparisons are case-insensitive.  If you are using a case-sensitive collation, you might want:

```
select t.*
from t
where lower(left(col, 1)) = lower(right(col, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

like this ?

```
select * 
from   yourTable c
where  substring(c.yourColumn, 1, 1) = substring(c.yourColumn, len(c.yourColumn), 1)
```

If your sql server is case sensitive (not by default) you need to put the substrings inside lower() functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Searchstring Varchar(2)='b'--Search charecter
;with cte1(Id, Searchstring)
As
(
SELECT 1,'EventName'                                    Union All
SELECT 2,'US colonies declare independence'             Union All
SELECT 3,'Daily Mail launched'                          Union All
SELECT 4,'India gains independence'                     Union All
SELECT 5,'DNA helix unravelled'                         Union All
SELECT 6,'Britain explodes first H bomb'                Union All
SELECT 7,'Charles de Gaulle established Fifth Republic' Union All
SELECT 8,'Harrow & WieldStone rail crash'
)
SELECT Id
    ,Searchstring
FROM cte1
WHERE CHARINDEX(@Searchstring, RIGHT(Searchstring, 1)) > 0
    AND CHARINDEX(@Searchstring, LEFT(Searchstring, 1)) > 0
```